# How do you use compound components in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to utilize the benefits of TypeScript compile-time checking, but yet also use the compound component design pattern in React. Everything seems to work fine if the child components don't have any props, but if you want to "forward" a prop passed to the parent into all the children, we get a TypeScript compile error. Here's a simplified version of the code I'm trying to do:

```js
import { Children, cloneElement } from 'react';

type ParentComponentProps = {
  props: any;
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
};

const ParentComponent = ({ children, props }: ParentComponentProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      {Children.map(children, (child) => {
        if (!child) {
          return null;
        }

        if (typeof child === 'string') {
          return child;
        }

        return cloneElement(child, props);
      })}
    </>
  );
};

type Child1Props = {
  name: string;
};

const Child1 = ({ name }: Child1Props) => {
  return <div>Child 1: {name}</div>;
};

type Child2Props = {
  name: string;
};

const Child2 = ({ name }: Child2Props) => {
  return <div>Child 2: {name}</div>;
};

export default function Homepage() {
  return (
    <ParentComponent props={{ name: 'Bob' }}>
      <Child1 />
      <Child2 />
    </ParentComponent>
  );
}
```

TypeScript doesn't understand that props passed into `<ParentComponent />` is sent down through into all the children automatically. But I don't want to have to specify `name={name}` for every single child component, hence why I'm using the compound component design pattern. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think TypeScript can help you much here, if you define a prop as required, no amount of React magic will allow you to render that component without that prop - You will need to define it as optional

Comment: That's what we ended up doing. Appreciate the help!